# Find a parameterization of the paraboloid $900z = 25x^2 + 36y^2$, $z \le 16$.

Tags: geometry, parametric, parametrization, cylindrical-coordinates

Find a parameterization of the paraboloid $900z = 25x^2 + 36y^2$, $z \le 16$.

The solution is $r(u, v) = (6v\cos(u), 5v\sin(u), v^2)$ where $0 \le u \le 2\pi$, $0 \le v \le 4$.

This is the first time I've been asked to parameterise a paraboloid, so I'm  struggling to deduce the reasoning behind this solution. I can tell the solution utilises cylindrical coordinates, but it's done so in a way that I've never seen.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to show the calculations and reasoning behind this solution. This will help me understand the solution and, therefore, solve similar paraboloid parameterisation problems in the future.

---

I recently asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226014/find-a-parameterization-of-the-paraboloid) relating to a similar problem from the same problem set. These are two different problems, and the questions relating to them are also completely different. I would like to thank Bubba for his assistance with the previous question.

Comment: What purpose do you follow ? You have asked the same question 11 hours ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2226014)! This not fair from somebody that is not a newcomer on this site. @Andrei

Comment: @JeanMarie It's not the same question. Notice that the problems are similar, yet different. The question itself is also different. Given this, I thought it was best to create a new question rather than make the previous one confusing by having multiple different problems and questions.

Comment: What is not fair in your attitude is precisely not to refer to the question and its solution by @bubba, exposing people with good will to repeat what has been done previously. The risk of confusion is zero if you explain things as they have happened "I have asked previously.... and the answer that has been given is  [see .. ]. Nevertheless..."

Comment: @JeanMarie Bubba's answer was exactly what I needed for understanding that specific problem. This is a completely new problem that has a different solution to what Bubba gave. My entire question is also different: I am not asking for a general solution, as was the case with Bubba's answer. I am now trying to understand the solution that was provided to me (for a different problem) rather than formulating my own. These two questions are in a completely different context, so I don't understand what the problem is? These are two completely different problems and questions.

Comment: @JeanMarie And notice that Bubba and Andrei's answers are completely different; that's because they're answering completely different problems and questions. I certainly appreciate Bubba's answer to the previous question: It was enlightening and helped me gain an understanding of these problems. I am now asking a completely different question for a different problem.

Comment: It's OK with your edit.

Comment: @JeanMarie I apologise if this seemed rude. It was certainly not my intention to devalue Bubba's contribution to the previous question. I have tremendous respect and appreciation for the members of MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's divide your equation by $900=25\cdot 36$ You get 
$$z=\frac{x^2}{6^2}+\frac{y^2}{5^2}$$
If we do the transformation $x/6=X$, and $y/5=Y$, this looks very much like the equation of a circle $X^2+Y^2=R^2$. In this case $R^2=z$. The parametric equation of the circle is then $X=R\cos\theta$ and $Y=R\sin\theta$. So you have $x=6R\cos\theta$, $y=5R\sin\theta$, $z=R^2$, where $\theta$ varies between $0$ and $2\pi$. Since $z$ is between $0$ and $16$, it means $R$ is between $0$ and $4$. If you rename your variables from $R$ to $v$, and from $\theta$ to $u$, you get your result